# Magento 1.9.1 Configurable swatches not generating images nor directory in Media > Catalog > Swatches > 1

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches, ce-1.9.1.1

We have identical local and staging environments on git, and on the same branch, but the configurable swatch assets are not displaying on the staging site. I've narrowed this down to the images not being present in the directory "media > catalog > swatches > 1…". When we load the page locally Magento will generate sized images within the directory, however this is not the case on our staging server. I'm trying to understand why this is the case. I've already confirmed the following:

1. Ensured all files are the same
2. Ensured databases are the same
3. Ensured the default and proper permissions are applied to each folder and file

Could anyone comment on why this is happening and what I might possibly do to resolve it?

Thanks you for your assistance in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Although the file directories, permissions, and databases were identical the environments differed in how Mac OS X handles file names. I ass-u-me-d (well, just the me part) that because they were both Linux, and that it was working locally, that the server had some permissions not allowing the cache directory to be created. When I did a php check in the productimg.php I found that the echo was looking for a file that wasn't there (by a few capital letters).

Mac OS-X can read the files correctly and generate the swatch cache with no problem, however on the staging linux server, it could not find these files so it could not generate them.

So moral of the story: Check file names and not all Linux systems are equal in how they handle filenames.